# Store multiple records while reading only once Issue using Protocol Buffer

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am using **Protocol Buffer** to **store** and **read** the records.
To store mutiple records using **writeDelimitedTo()** and to read using **parseDelimitedFrom()**.

While storing, **all records/messages** are storing successfully.

While reading, **only one record/message** is coming.

I don't know how is it so ? Am I storing the records in wrong way or something else ? Don't have any idea.

***user.proto***

```
option java_package = "main.java";
option java_outer_classname="ProtoUser";

message User {
   optional int32  id = 1;
   optional string name = 2;
   repeated Address addr = 3; 
   message Address {
   optional string city = 1;
   }
}
```

***WriteFile.java***

```
package com.io;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import main.java.ProtoUser;
import main.java.ProtoUser.User;

public class WriteFile {                   
     static User.Builder user = ProtoUser.User.newBuilder();
     static User.Address.Builder addr = ProtoUser.User.Address.newBuilder();
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("user.data");
       user.setId(1)
       .setName("luisat")
       .addAddr(addr.setCity("Weston"));
       user.build().writeDelimitedTo(output);

       user.setId(2)
       .setName("nitin")
       .addAddr(addr.setCity("falna"));
       user.build().writeDelimitedTo(output);
       output.close();
    }
}
```

***ReadFile.java***

```
package com.io;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import main.java.ProtoUser.User;

public class ReadFile {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        User user = User.parseDelimitedFrom( new FileInputStream("user.data") );
        System.out.println(user);
     }
}
```

Comment: Your `ReadFile` example code only calls `parseDelimitedFrom` once, so of course only gets the first record. I assume this isn't the full code -- can you please provide the full code that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @KentonVarda: I have written that much only. I created an object **user**. If I want to **read** values of **any field** then I have write like this - **user.getId()** but it gives me only **first record** id not further ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read multiple records, you need to call `parseDelimitedFrom` multiple times:

```
public class ReadFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("user.data");
    User user = User.parseDelimitedFrom(file);
    System.out.println(user);
    User user2 = User.parseDelimitedFrom(file);
    System.out.println(user2);
  }
}
```

Note that when there are no more records available, `parseDelimiteFrom` will return `null`.